# Xamarin Android player unable to connect to an existing instance

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin-android-player

Xamarin Android player is not responding with the message shown below.
I ended the task from the task manager and started it again many times but the same problem happens [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCE8J.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jljs3.png).

Can anyone help me?